# how does web server know which parameters to use on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

When a browser client calls forms.submit(), it sends up an http post request to a server.

Now, there could be multiple key => value pairs within the form, so my question is: How does the server know which pair(s) to use from the request string?

thanks!

Comment: It sends every input that has a `name` attribute (excluding buttons), and sends its corresponding `value` or *value* with it. It only sends the button that was clicked, provided a button was clicked

Comment: + reads the action attribute on the form element itself.

Comment: Also it skips form elements whose `disabled` property is `true`.

Comment: Also why do you think the server is just interested in one key/value pair? The form fields are put in the form because the server needs *all* of them.

Answer (score 0):

The post request is not sent to the server in a general way, but specifically to one .php (or .asp, or etc) file on the server. This file should contain code that:

1. Verifies that the desired keys have been received
2. Performs basic validation on each key->value pair
3. Submits any user-submitted data to various security functions to protect against SQL injection attacks, etc
4. Goes ahead and uses the key->value pairs that were submitted.  For example, it might grab the value from a key called `username` and the value from another key called `password` and use them to query a database to see if this user should be presented with the next page.

To answer your final question, the server knows which pairs to use from the request string because the programmer wrote both sides of the system. Therefore, the programmer must be careful to match up the NAME element of the Username input field (in the HTML), and grab the value from that specific key name when looking for the username that was submitted.

Perhaps an example would help.

OFF-THE-CUFF, UNTESTED EXAMPLE:

The Main Page: index.php

```
<form id="myForm" action="dologin.php" method="POST">
    Username: <br>
    <input type="text" name="dausername"><br>
    <br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="yerpass">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="do_submit">
</form>
```

The dologin.php page:

```
$uname = $_POST['dausername'];
$pword = $_POST['yerpass'];

$uname = security_check($uname);
$pword = security_check($pword);

$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$uname'";
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_result($result, 0);

if (!empty($r)) {
    //Now, check that the password matches
    if ($pword == $r['password']) {
        //The user has passed the security check (i.e. has "logged in") and can now see the secret stuff
        echo 'Welcome to our Private Server<br />';
        echo 'The pass code for our door is 4321';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Sorry, you must login first';
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP is running PHP?  Maybe it's a Rails server, or any of 1000 other possibilities.

Comment: True, but I trust the OP will understand that this is a php-specific example that answers his general, non code-specific question.